# How to retrieve rows in the required order in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows,

**table1**

[image]

When i m using the query

`"SELECT cat_title FROM table1 WHERE cat_id IN(21,10,25,4)"`

the result is in the order

> **cat_title**
>
> Bank
>
> Beauty Parlour
>
> Car
>
> Accomodation

But i need the result as given in the query like,

> **cat_title**
>
> Car
>
> Beaty Parlour
>
> Accomodation
>
> Bank

What will i do?

Comment: How do you get your initial order?  e.g. how are you determining tha the correct order is 21,10,25,4.

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor OP wants order as per conditions

Comment: Please note that the solutions given work, but break when the data changes, which often happens when moving data between dev, test and production environments. It also means end users can't change the ordering; it might be better to include an "orderSequence" column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT cat_title
FROM table1
WHERE cat_id IN(21,10,25,4)
ORDER BY (cat_id = 21) DESC, (cat_id = 10) DESC, (cat_id = 25) DESC, (cat_id = 4) DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT cat_title
FROM table1
WHERE cat_id IN(21,10,25,4)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cat_id, ('21,10,25,4'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT cat_title FROM table1 
 Where cat_id IN(21,10,25,4)
 ORDER BY (
            CASE WHEN cat_id = 21 THEN 0
          WHEN cat_id = 4 THEN 1
              WHEN cat_id = 10 THEN 2
          WHEN cat_id = 25 THEN 3
        END
           )
```