# Mysql Query Comes Back In Different Order

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a query that I run in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM title
WHERE id
IN (
(SELECT id
FROM title
WHERE id = '71'), 
(SELECT id
FROM title
WHERE id = '49'), 
(SELECT id
FROM title
WHERE id = '67'), 
(SELECT id
FROM title
WHERE id = '75'), 
(SELECT id
FROM title
WHERE id = '74')
)
```

I'm expecting my records in the order given: 71, 49, 67, 75, 74

But what I get back is in ascending order.

I cannot use another parameter for the search. What I need is for my records to come back in the order given by me. Is there a command that I can issue or how would I be able to work it.

Once again, I cannot use another query parameter to sort because I don't have one. I just need them back in the order they're being put in.

Is this even possible?

**Thank you!**

PS: PhP solutions only if I can sort the $result before I read the $row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FIELD` function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Or `FIND_IN_SET` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
/* your query begin */ ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 71, 49, 67, 75, 74)
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it :) you mean at the end

Comment: @NoodleHead, yes. By default(if `order` clause not wroted), mysql order records by primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, ('21,10,25,4'))
```

Go thorugh this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971780/how-to-retreive-rows-in-the-required-order-in-mysql)